# Как устранить ошибку Class PDO not found в Yii2 на хостинге Ru-Center?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, pdo, хостинг

Обычный хостинг на Ru-Center. PHP 7.
Расширения PDO и PDO_MYSQL включены.
Фреймворк Yii2.

При попытке выполнить миграцию...

```
php yii migrate
```

...происходит ошибка:

> PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class 'PDO'
>   not found'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратился к хостеру. Посоветовали выполнять команду следующего вида:

```
php -c ~/etc/php.ini /home/[host_user]/[domain_foder]/yii migrate
```

Но результатом этой команды выводится следующая ошибка:

> Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No
>   such file or directory'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в какую сторону думать...

Comment: а у них-то PDO в php включен ли?

Comment: `php -i | grep pdo`

Comment: php -i | grep pdo ничего не выводит, но в php.ini pdo.so и pdo_mysql.so присутствуют и раскомментированы